# Grails 2.5.0 null id for persisted object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When I am trying to save receiveTransaction I get this exception

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "letter_id" violates not-null constraint
>     Detail: Failing row contains (5, 0, RECEIVE, 67, nraed, 2015-06-22 12:56:17.111, null, ملوخية, 3, null, 1, f, 1, DONE, ps.police.parchive.LetterTransaction, null).
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
>       ... 9 more

Letter hasMany letterTransaction

LetterTransaction Domain :

```
class LetterTransaction {
ActionEnum action
Date dateTime
Party party
ArchiveStructure archiveStructure
Boolean reviewed = Boolean.FALSE
TransactionStatus status=TransactionStatus.PENDING
String notes
Long sequence
LetterTransaction relatedTransaction

RelatedLetter relatedLetter
List signs          = new ArrayList()
List reviewLogs     = new ArrayList()
List divisionPathes = new ArrayList()
List targets = new ArrayList()
String createdBy
boolean deleted

static transients = ['deleted']

static belongsTo = [letter:Letter]
static hasMany = [
        targets:Party,
        // related letters in case this letter is related to other letters (Attachments)

        // actions have bean specified by organization manager التاشيرات
        signs:Sign,
        // all reviewing actions have bean taken for this letter
        reviewLogs:ReviewLog,
        // this devision path describes where scans have bean saved, according the ArchiveStructure for this letter
        divisionPathes:DivisionPath
]
```

}

in controller

```
    LetterTransaction sendTransactionInstance = LetterTransaction.get(params.long("transactionId"))
    LetterTransaction receiveTransaction=new LetterTransaction()
    receiveTransaction.action=ActionEnum.RECEIVE
    receiveTransaction.letter=Letter.get(sendTransactionInstance.letter.id)
    receiveTransaction.status=TransactionStatus.DONE
    receiveTransaction.relatedTransaction=sendTransactionInstance
    receiveTransaction.party=InternalDepartment.findByCoreId(session.departmentId)
    receiveTransaction.dateTime=new Date()
    receiveTransaction.sequence=params.long("sequence")
    receiveTransaction.targets=[sendTransactionInstance?.party]
    receiveTransaction.notes = params.comments
    receiveTransaction.archiveStructure = ArchiveStructure.get(params.long("archiveStructure.id"))

    if(!receiveTransaction.hasErrors() && receiveTransaction.save(flush: true,failOnError: true)){
        sendTransactionInstance.letter.addToTransactions(receiveTransaction)
        sendTransactionInstance.letter.save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
        //copy all scans to the new folder
        manageService.copyLetterScansFromOrganization(sendTransactionInstance, sendTransactionInstance?.party?.coreId,null, getCurrentUser())
        render "OK"
    }else{
        def errors=g.renderErrors(bean: receiveTransaction)
        render errors
    }
```

Comment: Make sure `Letter.get(sendTransactionInstance.letter.id)` is not `null`

Comment: letter in letterTransaction is nullable false .. LetterTransaction belongs to letter so it can't be null

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the reason I fixed this by saving the letter instance after adding letterTransaction instead of saving receiveTransaction  .. this is too strange.